# In React js, state from one browser tab is passed to another tab while displaying Modal

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Js UI, where I am displaying Modal on click of a button. The issue is that I am displaying some data on Modal which is from state. If I open one more tab of the application, and then come back to my current tab and click the button to open the Modal, the state is from previous tab and hence the data is not correct. I want to get the current tab state and not the other tab state. Could anyone please help?

Here is the sample code:

renderModal() {

```
const { message, reject, dataValidations, tooltips, data } = this.state;
```

}

Comment: React apps are generally intended to run in a single tab. If you want multiple browser windows to use the same state, you need some way to transfer the information from one window to the next, for example by using `localStorage` or syncing with a server.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the tab, the state gets cleared. You need to store the state in client side. You can use **localStorage** or ***cookie*** to store the state value and reload data from the storage.

For example:

```
componentDidMount(){
    // read data from local storage
    const data = localstorage.getItem("key");
    this.setState(data);
}
```

to store data in local storage:

```
localstorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

this is how you can read and store data in local storage. And you'll get tab data even after reloading.